# What is "status : setting_configured" in config of Crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm integrating crashlytics to my own lib. I have an issue to setup the Crashlytics.

Here is some config of mine.

```
....

"app": {
        "identifier": "com.@@@.@@@",
        "status": "settings_configured",
        "url": "https:\/\/api.crashlytics.com\/spi\/v1\/platforms\/android\/apps\/com.@@@.@@@",
        "reports_url": "https:\/\/reports.crashlytics.com\/spi\/v1\/platforms\/android\/apps\/com.@@@.@@@\/reports",
        "ndk_reports_url": "https:\/\/reports.crashlytics.com\/sdk-api\/v1\/platforms\/android\/apps\/com.@@@.@@@\/minidumps",
        "update_required": false
    },

....
```

I thought it's succeeded to initialize Crashlytics, but it's not appear on dashboard.

What is mean "status": "settings_configured"?

Could you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. This means that we have registered a build event but not a run event for your app. Depending on your config, you may need us to manually intervene through our support team, or you may be able to get up and running by running the app on a real device.